# Inserting Records into ASE linked table results in single-row update/delete affected more than one row of a linked table

Tags: database, ms-access, odbc, ms-access-2016, linked-tables

In Microsoft Access 2016 i have a link to an ASE table trough the Adaptative Server Enterprise ODBC driver.

The table is used only has a data pass table for database admins
On the server side the table has no indexes, primary keys or foreign keys

When linking the table in access, it always asks you to identify the primary key/keys in order to be able to insert records into it.

In Microsoft Access 2010 they had it working by identifying 10 fields as primary keys just so that records could be inserted from access

In Micrososft Access 2016 i am getting the error:

> Single-row update/delete affected more than one row of a linked table.
>   Unique index contains duplicate values. (Error 3362)

Is there a way to allow access to insert records into this table without declaring a primary key, since the server table has none?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Nope, Access requires an unique identifier to modify records. A composite key can be used, though

Comment: Everything i've read goes in this direction.
But... I have this same setup in another table that has no primary key assigned
When linking in access i choose a combination of fields that work as a composite key and i have no problem inserting into it

Comment: That's exactly what I just said. You can use a composite key. But it needs to be unique

Comment: Yes, the strange thing to me is , with an empty table inserting only one record i get the same error

Comment: That's certainly odd. I don't have experience with ASE, but generally this error should not occur at all on inserts, only on updates and deletes.